# detect_leaks vs leak_check_at_exit?

Tags: memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I used **AddressSanitizer** to check memory leak for my application but am getting confused about the difference between these two flags: `detect_leaks` vs `leak_check_at_exit`.

I thought the below code should report memory leak even when `leak_check_at_exit=0` because the leak would already happened during each loop rather than after the main function returns:

```
int main() {
    void *mem;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        mem = malloc(1024);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With `detect_leaks=1:leak_check_at_exit=1` the program does give a correct report of memory leak:

```
=================================================================
==73448==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1024000 byte(s) in 1000 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f0933f053f8 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3+0xc23f8)
    #1 0x42c8c1 in main src/main.cpp:10
    #2 0x7f0931b05ec4 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
```

But with `detect_leaks=1:leak_check_at_exit=0` it does NOT report any memory leak. To me it looks like setting `leak_check_at_exit=0` is equivalent to setting `detect_leaks=0`.

**Question**: 
What is the difference between `detect_leaks` and `leak_check_at_exit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeakSanitizer works by analyzing program memory for pointers to allocated chunks. The analysis is extremely slow and so is performed only at the end of execution (you can also run it by calling `__lsan_do_leak_check`).

When you set `leak_check_at_exit=0` you effectively disable Lsan. You could manually insert `__lsan_do_leak_check` at every loop iteration but this would slow the program down and also may not play well if you app had multiple threads.